# Fragment to fragment communication with viewmodel without host activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, viewmodel, modularization

There is a straight forward implementation for `fragment` to `fragment` communucation using `viewmodel` and a host `activity` (`ViewModel by activityViewModels()`). However I have a case where there is no intermediate activity for communication.

I am working on a modularized application with modules including `app` and `wallet`. `app` depends on `wallet` and the `wallet` module has a `fragment`: `WalletFragment` that can be accessed by the `app`'s module `MainActivity`.

Now if I create a `viewModel` instance for `app`'s module `MainActivity`, I won't be able to access it from `wallet` module because `wallet` module has no dependency on the `app` module. **How can I achieve this?**

**To the main question:** I have another scenerio where the `WalletFragment` calls a new `BottomSheetFragment` in the same `wallet` module. Is there a way I can create a `ViewModel` instance for this `WalletFragment` that can be accessed by the `BottomSheetFragment` without having to take the route of `ViewModel by activityViewModels()`. In other words is there such thing as `ViewModel by fragmentViewModels()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something called `SharedViewModel`, for example:

This is the viewModel that will be shared.

```
class ShareableViewModel(): ViewModel(){

    val message = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun sendMessage(text: String) {
        message.value = text
    }
}
```

And now the `FirstFragment` is the fragment that will send something, in this case, just a string.

```
class FirstFragment: Fragment(){

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        val shareableViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShareableViewModel::class.java)
        shareableViewModel.sendMessage("Message from first Fragment")
    }
}
```

Finally, `SecondFragment` is the fragment that is receiving the message fragment `Fragment1`

```
class SecondFragment: Fragment(){

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val shareableViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShareableViewModel::class.java)
        shareableViewModel.message.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        //Receiving the message
        })
    }
}
```

I hope it can help. For more details, you can see:

- https://blog.mindorks.com/shared-viewmodel-in-android-shared-between-fragments